# Gurobi Interactive Shell execute automatic commands through a file

Tags: python, batch-file, gurobi

I want to execute automatic commands through a file in the Gurobi interactive Shell.

I tried the following:

`solve.bat` (should do all the work - start gurobi and execute the commands in `.cmd`)

```
@ECHO OFF
cd D:\gurobi651\
run.bat -f PowerLPData.cmd
EXIT
```

`run.bat` (starts Gurobi interactive shell)

```
cmd.exe /c gurobi.bat
```

`PowerLPData.cmd` (provides the commands to execute)

```
m = read("PowerLPData.mps")
m.ModelSense = -1
m.update()
m.optimize()
m.write("PowerLPResult.sol")
quit()
```

**My intention is to execute the commands in `PowerLPData.cmd` in the interactive shell of gurobi, but this does not work. The interactive shell starts when I run `solve.bat` and nothing happens after.**

I have done the same princip for CPLEX and it works. CPLEX has an executable `CPLEX.exe` instead of `run.bat` and a customized `.cmd` file.

I think that the Gurobi interactive shell is a python shell, which does not work with `.cmd files`, but I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: You can also use the Gurobi Command Line tool: http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/solving_a_model2.html

Answer (score 0):

gurobi.bat is a Python interpreter that includes the gurobipy library. To run your Python script using gurobi.bat, rename it to PowerLPData.py, then run `gurobi.bat PowerLPData.py` from a Windows shell.

Comment: I tried this but it does not affect anything. The commands in PowerLPData.py don't get executed.

Comment: Try `examples\build\runpython.bat` from the Gurobi distribution; this shows how to run Python code from the Windows shell.